# WebClient UploadValues connection closed out unexpectedly

Tags: c#, webclient

I am getting an error when trying to send post data to my php server.
This call works from one place in my program, but not the second.

My php code is just a simple echo, and I've tested the page and it runs fine.

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll The
>   underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly.

```
public static class NetworkDeploy 
{
    public delegate void CallBack(string response);

    public static void SendPacket(string url, CallBack callback) 
    {
        SynchronizationContext callersCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
                values["test"] = "test";
                // exception occurs at the next line
                byte[] uploadResponse = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", values);
                string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(uploadResponse);
                if (callback != null) callersCtx.Post(new SendOrPostCallback((_) => callback.Invoke(response)), null);
            }
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
    }
}
```

I have tried putting the exception line in a for loop like this:

```
byte[] uploadResponse = null;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    try
    {
        // exception occurs at the next line
        uploadResponse = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", values);
        break;
    } catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

and the php code is simply

```
<?php
echo "Success";
```

Comment: Is this part runs once or in a loop? And are you tried HttpClient instead of WebClient.

Comment: It runs once, but I've tried it in a loop.  I am stuck at .Net 4.0 and can't use 4.5

Comment: I'd recommend looking at using `HttpClient` which has been optomized for these kind of operations.

Also, I can see where you start the thread but where do you wait for the thread to finish and get the result?

Comment: Handling the response is taken care of, I simplified it for the post.  The exception occurs at the UploadValues line.  Unfortunately I can't use net 4.5, so HttpClient isn't available

Comment: This isn't a direct answer and using HttpClient is a bit of a tangent. But it looks like you can get a working version on 4.0 from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/

Comment: do you have a sample of the loop where it fails and how the task is handled? I'd like to run a proof of concept here to see if i can get the same error but the above snipped is only partial

Comment: Yeah, I just found that.  This is a very large project (over a million lines of code) and I'm not ready to add packages just yet (but might if I can't find a better solution).

Comment: Let me post more code.  It works the first time I call it though, just not the second.

Comment: I've made a quick test on my end that calls a local API, the server waits 5 seconds before replying. Each time i run the code it works... I think it's something in the loop. Is it possible to get a sample of the loop after a quick test to make sure the sample still doesn't work in your environment?

Comment: I just edited the code.  I have tried putting the exception line in a 10 iteration for loop with a break on success and it fails on each call.

Comment: What goes on the wire if you inspect with [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)? That PHP code works also if you POST to it?

Comment: Just installed fiddler ... hang on

Comment: I'm sure the php code is solid, I've tested it.  For testing, I have a simple echo "Success";  I edited the post to reflect that.  This is on localhost, and fiddler isn't seeing the traffic, need to learn to use fiddler ...

Comment: What happens if you remove the thread, and just run the using block in the SendPacket method?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in my test environment with `SynchronizationContext.Current` but this might be an environmental thing. Once I set it to a `new SynchronizationContext()` everything ran okay for me. I did 5 loops and they all invoked my callback okay. Can you try a test using `new SynchronizationContext()` and see if this makes a difference?

Comment: Tried new SynchornizationContext(), requires the thread to be STA.  The callback needs to run on the main UI thread because it deals with a window.

Comment: Fiddler says I am getting a 408 response - timeout

Comment: Try `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(callersCtx);` in the thread body?

Comment: Is this running under WPF or WinForms? Or something else?

Comment: It is under WPF.  The exception occurs before the callback though, and if I remove the callback entirely, I still get the same exception. I find it odd that the code works perfectly the first time I call it and fails the second ...

Comment: Can you connect using a IE.  If you can compare fiddler results with IE results.  Look at headers and see differences.  Usually you have a wrong or missing header.   The 408 is a timeout error.  Server usually don't respond when request is wrong to make it harder for hackers to get into a site.

Comment: Ah, lol.  I feel like an idiot.  I had a misspelling in the url name.

Comment: I have your code verbatim in a .NET 4.0 class library. I made a WPF App (4.0) with a button and a TextBlock. Button calls the method, posting to a php server 3x in a row in the event handler. The message goes to the server and the callback gets fired each time. There's probably something else outside the scope of this code affecting things

Comment: Yes, it was indeed programmer error.  I had a simple typo in the url name!  I really appreciate all your help!  I tested your code as well, and it works, so I'm going to accept it as the answer!

Comment: haha, I hate it when that happens, we've all been there before. Just glad it's working now and that we're not all crazy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue is coming from the use of `SynchronizationContext.Current` and how the delegate is being invoked to call back into your main UI thread.

I've written a sample proof of concept to do this using a task factory and anonymous delegates that should let you invoke the tasks from your UI thread and then handle the completed result on the UI thread.

I hope this solves the problem:

```
    Task<string> SendPacket(string url)
    {
        return Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
                values["test"] = "test";
                // exception occurs at the next line
                byte[] uploadResponse = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", values);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(uploadResponse);
            }
        });
    }

    void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            SendPacket("http://localhost:8733/api/values").ContinueWith(task => DoSomethingOnCallback(task.Result));
        }
    }

    void DoSomethingOnCallback(string response)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
```